# Use pthread condition variable in ping-pong test

Tags: c, multithreading, performance, parallel-processing, pthreads

I am using pthread condition variable as a synchronization primitive in a ping-pong test. The ping-pong test consists of two threads execute alternatively. Each thread writes to the other thread's memory and wake it up using signal, then wait and sleep on its own memory which will be written by the other thread later. Here is my first version. It works fine when I loop this ping-pong test for 10,000 times, but when I change to 100,000 times, it will hang occasionally. N=1,000,000 will make it hang definitely. I tried to debug and print out the loop number for each loop, but the program never hangs again after I add the print statement, which is annoying. Here is the ping-pong test code:

```
for(i=0; i<N+1; i++)
{
    if(i==N)
    {
        pthread_cond_signal(&cond[dest]);
        break;
    }
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex[dest]);
    messages[dest]=my_rank;
    pthread_cond_signal(&cond[dest]);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex[dest]);
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex[my_rank]);
    while(pthread_cond_wait(&cond[my_rank], &mutex[my_rank]) && messages[my_rank]!=dest);
    messages[my_rank]=my_rank;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex[my_rank]);
    printf("rank=%ld i=%ld messages[%ld]=%ld\n", my_rank, i, my_rank, messages[my_rank]);
}
```

Then I tried a second version which works and never hangs, even I set N to 1,000,000. I changed from two mutexes to one mutex which is shared by the two condition variables. I am not sure if it is the right way to go but this one never hangs again. Here is the code:

```
for(i=0; i<N+1; i++)
{
    if(i==N)
    {
        pthread_cond_signal(&cond[dest]);
        break;
    }
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex[0]);
    messages[dest]=my_rank;
    pthread_cond_signal(&cond[dest]);
    while(pthread_cond_wait(&cond[my_rank], &mutex[0]) && messages[my_rank]!=dest);
    messages[my_rank]=my_rank;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex[0]);
}
```

I am very confused. Could somebody help me explain why the first version hangs but the second version does not? Is it correct for two condition variable sharing a single mutex?

Thanks.

---

Thanks for everyone, especially caf. Here is my final code that works without hanging.

```
for(i=0; i<N+1; i++)
{
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex[dest]);
    messages[dest]=my_rank;
    pthread_cond_signal(&cond[dest]);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex[dest]);
    if(i!=N)
    {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex[my_rank]);
        while(messages[my_rank]!=dest)
            pthread_cond_wait(&cond[my_rank], &mutex[my_rank]);
        messages[my_rank]=my_rank;
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex[my_rank]);
    }
}
```

Comment: The condition in your `while()`-loop is *never* true. `man pthread_cond_wait: [...]RETURN VALUE All condition variable functions return 0 on  success  and  a  non-zero error code on error. ERRORS pthread_cond_init,   pthread_cond_signal,  pthread_cond_broadcast and pthread_cond_wait never return an error code.[...]`. So the first condition of the `&&` is always false, and short-circuit evaluation means the second condition isn't even checked.

Comment: @EOF `pthread_cond_wait` returns non-zero when it is not waked up by `pthread_cond_signal` or `pthread_cond_broadcast`. I am not sure why the man page says it never returns an error code, maybe the implementation can ensure this never happen? Anyway, putting `pthread_cond_wait` in `while()` should not be the problem. The second condition is not quite necessary in this case because there are only two threads here, however, I should change the order of the conditions for `&&` in a more general case.

Comment: @EOF Actually, the fact that `pthread_cond_wait` is never true is the best possible outcome for us in terms of performance.

Comment: the posted code displays a 'race' condition.  strongly suggest re-thinking the logic/execution flow.

Comment: @user3629249 Do you mind elaborating your point? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in this line:

```
while (pthread_cond_wait(&cond[my_rank], &mutex[my_rank]) && messages[my_rank]!=dest);
```

If the 'dest' thread gets scheduled after you unlock `mutex[dest]` and before you lock `mutex[my_rank]`, it will set `messages[my_rank]` and signal the condition variable, *before* this thread calls `pthread_cond_wait()`, so this thread will wait forever.

The fix for this is very easy: test `messages[my_rank]` *before* waiting on the condition variable.  You also don't want `&&` here, because you always want to keep looping as long as `messages[my_rank] != dest` is true - you don't want to break out at the first non-zero return from `pthread_cond_wait()`.  So if you want to ignore errors from `pthread_cond_wait()` (as your original does, and this is perfectly fine if you aren't using error-checking or robust mutexes, since those are the only times `pthread_cond_wait()` is allowed to fail), use:

```
while (messages[my_rank] != dest)
    pthread_cond_wait(&cond[my_rank], &mutex[my_rank]);
```

The reason that your alternate version doesn't have this bug is because the lock is continuously held between signalling the `dest` thread and waiting on the condition variable, so the `dest` thread doesn't get a chance to run until we're definitely waiting.

---

As for your supplementary question:

> Is it correct for two condition variable sharing a single mutex?

Yes, this is allowed, but the converse is not (you **cannot** have two threads waiting on the same condition variable at the same time, using different mutexes).

Answer (score 1):

first of all, sorry, i wanted to put that into comment but i still can not.

Well, in your code, i don't understand much what is "my_rank" and "dest", as i think my_rank should maybe vary within those loops, but i have found the following that may help you : http://www.cs.cf.ac.uk/Dave/C/node31.html#SECTION003125000000000000000

there it's said :

> You should always call pthread_cond_signal() under the protection of the same mutex used with the condition variable being signaled. Otherwise, the condition variable could be signaled between the test of the associated condition and blocking in pthread_cond_wait(), which can cause an infinite wait.

As you're using multiple mutexes in the first version, that may be the reason.

an admin could move that to comments, please?

Comment: Thank you for your response. As I described in the question, there are two threads, and their IDs are 0 and 1 which are fixed. So for thread 0, my_rank is 0 and dest is 1. Similar for thread 1. In "You should always call pthread_cond_signal() under the protection of the same mutex used with the condition variable being signaled.", I guess it is talking about a single condition variable, but I am using two condition variables here. Maybe I did not understand this right.